# When I use PTR operator with indirect operands in MASM?

Tags: assembly, masm

I am confused with using PTR operator with mov instruction

In my book,

```
.data
byteVal BYTE 10h
.code
mov esi, OFFSET, byteVal
mov al, [esi]
```

this code is valid

but

```
Employee STRUCT
   IDNum BYTE "000000000"
   Years WORD 0
Employee ENDS

.data
worker Employee <>
.code
mov esi, OFFSET worker
mov ax, [esi].Years
```

this code is invalid

but

```
 mov ax, (Employee PTR [esi]).Years
```

this code is valid

I want to know When I use PTR operator with mov instruction and indirect operand

Comment: You need to use PTR to cast something to a different type. `[esi]` has no type so you need to cast to something else unless the type can be inferred from the other operand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the assembler precisely what struct esi is pointing to... what if there were multiple structures with elements of the same name (in this case .Years)?

You can accomplish a similar thing by putting an ASSUME in force:

```
    assume esi:ptr Employee
```

Then when esi no longer holds a valid Employee ptr:

```
    assume esi:nothing
```

Comment: Thank you for clear answer! I have one more question. Why is it possible when I use "mov al, [esi]" in the first code block?

Comment: "mov al,[esi]" doesn't involve a structure member -- it's simply an opcode to load the byte at [esi] into al.  When you use  [esi].Years the assembler needs to know the offset of Years to encode into the instruction.  There _could be_ 10 structures with "Years" members; the assembler needs to be explicitly told which type esi points to.